# Students and Test Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

> Anna, Ben, and Chris write an exam that consists of only one question:
>   "What is 26 times 26"?Both Anna and Ben give the correct answer with probability 9/10. Chris gives the correct answer with probability 6/10.
>
> -Assume that the three students do not cheat, i.e., each student answers the question
>   independently of the other two students. Determine the probability that at least two
>   of them give the correct answer.
>
> -Assume that Anna and Ben do not cheat, but Chris copies Anna's answer. Determine the probability that at least two of them give the correct answer.
>
> Hint: The answer to the second part is smaller than the answer to the first part.

I don't even know how to approach this problem. any help on how to start or hints on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes. Pr(A|B)=Pr(AnB)/Pr(B) but I don't know how and when to use it in this problem

Comment: **Hint:** *Independence* means : $P(A\mid B) = \Box$?

Answer (score 1):

You have events $A,B,C$ with given probabilities.

> a)  Assume that the three students do not cheat, i.e., each student answers the question independently of the other two students. Determine the probability that at least two of them give the correct answer.

Find: 
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P_a & = \mathsf P((A\cap B) \cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C))
& \text{use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, or}
 \\[2ex] & = \mathsf P((A\cap ( B\cup C )) \cup (\neg A\cap B\cap C))
 & \text{Partition the event into $\\$ a union of exclusive events}
 \\[1ex] & = \Box\end{align}$

Can you complete from here?

> b) Assume that Anna and Ben do not cheat, but Chris copies Anna's answer. Determine the probability that at least two of them give the correct answer.

Here $C=A$ surely, so if Anna gives the correct answer, at least two students do, and if Anna gives the wrong answer, at most one does.

Find: $\mathsf P_b = \Box$

Comment: shouldn't AnBnC be considered for the first part? at least 2 can also mean that all of them give the right answer

Comment: Yes, @user53073. It is a subset of the union of the intersecting pairs.  $(A\cap B\cap C) \subseteq (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)$